# Is there any Tool available to validate sabre production credentials

Tags: sabre

Is there any tool available to check sabre production credentials - (PCC) and can check the fares which we get in response like travelport provide us demo site where we can add our custom credentials and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Sabre-io-docs](https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs) , [sabre Dev Studio](https://developer.sabre.com/login/login?r=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.sabre.com%2Fapps%2Fmykeys&h=a3a367e9774120c18c096f94eabba2c1) or you can also checkout apps at [Sabre Red App centre](https://www.sabreredappcentre.sabre.com/).

Comment: @Abrar I already referred Dev Studio but i couldn't find it, if you can share the direct link that would be better

Comment: https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs , login and start testing based on the api you want.